# C++ Returning Type Deduction Failing

Tags: c++, decltype, trailing-return-type

The return type on the fmap function does not auto deduce to be the right type of Option

Can anyone help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<class T>
class Option{
public:
    Option() : value_(nullptr){
    }
    Option(T const& value) : value_(std::move(value)){

    }
    Option(T&& value) : value_(std::make_shared<T>(std::move(value))){

    }
    Option(Option const&) = default;
    Option(Option&&) = default;
    Option& operator = (Option const&) = default;
    Option& operator = (Option&&) = default;

    template<class U>
    auto fmap(std::function<U ( T const& ) > func) -> Option<decltype( func(std::declval<T>() ) )>{
        return Option<U>(func(*value_));
    }

    template<class U>
    Option<U> operator >>= (std::function<Option<U> ( T const& ) > func){
        if(value_ == nullptr)
            return Option<U>();
        return func(value_);
    }

    static Option<T> Unit(T const& value){
        return Option<T>(value);
    }

    static Option<T> Unit(T&& value){
        return Option<T>(std::move(value));
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> value_;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{


    Option<int> o(55);
    auto f = [](int const& i){
        return i + 1;
    };
    auto result = o.fmap<int>(f);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<class T>
class Option{
public:
    Option() : value_(nullptr){
    }
    Option(T const& value) : value_(std::move(value)){

    }
    Option(T&& value) : value_(std::make_shared<T>(std::move(value))){

    }
    Option(Option const&) = default;
    Option(Option&&) = default;
    Option& operator = (Option const&) = default;
    Option& operator = (Option&&) = default;

    template<class Function>
    auto fmap(Function func) -> Option<decltype(func( std::declval<T>() ))>{
        return Option<decltype(func( std::declval<T>() ))>(func(*value_));
    }

    template<class Function>
    auto operator >>= (Function func) -> decltype(func( std::declval<T>() )){
        if(value_ == nullptr)
            return decltype(func( std::declval<T>() ))();
        return func(*value_);
    }

    void foreach(std::function<void ( T const& ) > func){
        return func(*value_);
    }

    static Option<T> Unit(T const& value){
        return Option<T>(value);
    }

    static Option<T> Unit(T&& value){
        return Option<T>(std::move(value));
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> value_;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{


    Option<int> o(55);
    auto f = [](int const& i){
        return i + 1;
    };

    auto result = o.fmap(f);

    auto tresult = result >>= [](int const& v){
        return Option<int>::Unit(v * 2);
    };

    tresult.foreach([](int const& i){
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would be nice if I could use std::function